# How do I use a TreeStore with 'auto' mappings?

Tags: tree, sencha-touch

I have a model that looks like this:

```
Ext.regModel('TreeItem', {
    fields: [
             { name: 'ItemId', type: 'int' },
             { name: 'ItemType', type: 'string' },
             { name: 'Article', type: 'auto' },
             { name: 'Container', type: 'auto' },
             { name: 'Category', type: 'auto'}]
});
```

The ItemType indicates whether that specific item should be rendered as an Article, Container, or Category.  Each of the Article, Container, and Category objects has an associated ArticleName, ContainerName, and CategoryName.

I'd like to render these names in a NestedList based on the record's ItemType.  So I overrode the getItemTextTpl like this:

```
getItemTextTpl: function (recordnode)
            {
                var template = '<div class="{ItemType}-icon"></div>';
                if (recordnode.firstChild.attributes.record.data["ItemType"] == 'Article')
                {
                    template += recordnode.firstChild.attributes.record.data['Article']["ArticleName"];
                }
                if (recordnode.firstChild.attributes.record.data["ItemType"] == 'Container')
                {
                    template += recordnode.firstChild.attributes.record.data['Container']["ContainerName"];
                }
                if (recordnode.firstChild.attributes.record.data["ItemType"] == 'Category')
                {
                    template += recordnode.firstChild.attributes.record.data['Category']["CategoryName"];
                }
                return template;   
            }
```

However, it appears that getItemTextTpl is only called once for each level of the tree, so there's no way to render the information for each list item.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done.  I genericized my objects and used the regular mappings. You can't use auto mappings with a template.

Answer (score 3):

You should move your conditional logic from the function into the template. Here's an example that demonstrates how you would go about doing this (although you will probably have to modify it to get it to work):

```
getItemTextTpl: function (recordnode)
    {
        var template = '<div class="{ItemType}-icon"></div>' +
            '<tpl if="ItemType === \'Article\'">' +
                '{ArticleName}' +
            '</tpl>' +
            '<tpl if="ItemType === \'Container\'">' +
                '{ContainerName}' +
            '</tpl>' +
            '<tpl if="ItemType === \'Category\'">' +
                '{CategoryName}' +
            '</tpl>' +
        '</div>';
        return template;   
    }
```

I created a [NestedList demo](http://sencha-nested-list.heroku.com/) that uses this technique. The [code is on github](https://github.com/nelstrom/Sencha-Touch-nested-list-demo/blob/master/public/app/views/Viewport.js), and there is also [a screencast](http://vimeo.com/20580117) demonstrating how it was built. You might also want to check out my two part series of screencasts on the subject of Xtemplates ([part one](http://vimeo.com/16289757) and [part two](http://vimeo.com/16289990))

Comment: Yes, this is what I would have done, but each of the names are inside the auto mappings to the article, container, and category objects, and I would prefer not to move them out because there is a lot of other info in those objects that I would like to use to provide a very rich display.  (The code above is just an example.)  Is it possible to access attributes on auto objects in a template?

Comment: I think it should be possible to translate your javascript conditionals into the `<tpl if=""/>` format, but having to escape certain characters makes it ugly and unpleasant to read. In this situation I would normally recommend moving the inline conditionals from the `<tpl>` tags into member functions. But sadly, I don't know of any way to attach a member function in this context, because `getItemTextTpl` is supposed to return a string object, rather than an xTemplate.